# how to check ajax response array value has matching string

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is the array from my Ajax response 
How to find the response array value has matching string.

```
 Array
 (
 [0] => test
 [1] => test1
 [2] => new test1
 )
```

from the array i need to find if it has test then say "In Array ".

```
var camp_name = $(this).val();//I will type as "test"...
$.ajax({url: "getCampaignInfo.php",data: camp_name, success: function(result){

      if($.inArray(camp_name, result) > -1) 
          {
            alert("In Array");
          }
      else
         {
            alert(result);
         }

}});
```

Comment: Why are you not checking that directly inside your PHP script, and have that return a true/false answer to your JavaScript then …?

Comment: thats great but i have trouble passing value into it as im trying this  $camp_name =$_POST['camp_name']; but the campname is empty

Comment: That’s because you are not actually passing any parameter name. `data: camp_name` should be `data: { "camp_name" : camp_name}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,in this result must be an array

```
if($.inArray(camp_name, result) != -1) 
      {
        alert("In Array");
      }
  else
     {
        alert(result);
     }
```

Comment: Sorry no output